# Why this db_query used in Drupal 7 Rules custom PHP crashes my website

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-rules

I can execute this code in a page node like a PHP code, but when I try to run on a custom php action in Drupal 7 Rules, my website crashes (white screen). What's wrong?

```
$OrderID_miquel="40";
$query = db_query('Select MAX(field_delivery_package_numerical_value) AS MaxDelivery , order_id , nid FROM {field_data_field_delivery_package_numerical} , {uc_order_products} WHERE order_id = :order_id' , array( ':order_id' => $OrderID_miquel));
```

Comment: Try to put the $OrderID_miquel=40 as an integer instead of text. And check the logs, in reports or the apache logs.

Comment: Thanks Salvador. Finally, the problem was generated by MAX().

Comment: You are welcome, good to know you solved it :)